# Zend PDO ODBC Database selection

Tags: pdo, db2, odbc, zend-framework2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to adapt the Zend Skeleton App to use an ODBC connection. I am able to set up a PDO connection outside of Zend (same table, server, everything) like this:

```
new PDO('odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=<serverName>;HOSTNAME=<serverName>;DATABASE=<databaseName>;', 
            '<userName>', '<password>');
$r = $this->conn->query('SELECT * FROM <databaseName>.<tableName>');
```

But when I add this information to the global.php file:

```
'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=<serverName>;HOSTNAME=<serverName>;DATABASE=<databaseName>;',
),
```

And in local.php:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'username' => '<userName>',
        'password' => '<password>',
    ),
);
```

I get an error that the table is not found:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 0 [IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL0204 - <tableName> in <userName - yes you read that right> type *FILE not found.
```

I believe this is because my prefixed `<databaseName>.<tableName>` is being wrapped in double quotes when the query runs through Zend. **I cannot explain why Zend is looking for my table under userName.** However, I cannot get PDO to recognize the table without the prefix, even though I have tried declaring my database in the initialization of the PDO every way I can think of.

Is there a way for PDO to actually pick up the database name so I don't need the prefix? Or is there a way to tell Zend to use the prefix (not lumped in the quotes with the table name)?

Please pardon if I'm using the wrong language here - I get a little lost between Schema, Database, Library, File, Table, etc. when I'm going between SQL and iSeries.

I really appreciate any help you can offer, Zend is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by finally finding an addition to my DSN that properly specified the library/schema I wanted to work under. This site (http://www.sqlthing.com/HowardsODBCiSeriesFAQ.htm) gave me the parameter `DBQ=<libraryName>` which finally worked for me after trying `DATABASE`, `DBNAME`, and many others.

Now that my library is properly specified in my connection string, I don't need to prefix the table name so my queries work even though I never got Zend to take a schema in the construction of a TableGateway. I'm going to mark this as an answer for now, but if anyone knows how to send a schema name to a new TableGateway I would be happy to change that.

Comment: I changed my connection string to `'odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=<serverName>;HOSTNAME=<serverName>;DBQ=<libraryName>'` (I think - it's been a while)

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with PDO, as I use ibm_db2, but the database name can be found with the CL command `WRKRDBDIRE`.

With *SQL naming, an unqualified table name (`SELECT * FROM TABLENAME`) is implicitly qualified with the user profile name.  So if SARAHK is executing the select, it becomes `SELECT * FROM SARAHK.TABLENAME`.  So the error you're seeing indicates that IBM i thinks you have an unqualified table name.

If you could configure the ODBC driver to use *SYSTEM naming, it would use the library list to locate unqualified table names.

I'm an old school RPG programmer, so I'm more familiar with the traditional names; here's a cheat sheet:

- Library -> Schema
- File -> Table
- Member -> No SQL equivalent - use ALIAS

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand the user default and for the cheat sheet! Configuring the driver won't work for me, unfortunately, but hopefully someone with this problem will benefit from your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I just went through the process of converting the tutorial to connect to IBM i with the ODBC driver but did not want to specify (a.k.a. hardcode) the library in the connection string.  Setting the "NAMING" parameter to '1' (*SYS rather than *SQL) will use the *USRLIBL of the user's connection/profile/JOBD (WRKJOBD INLLIBL(  ...) ).  If you use *SQL naming, it will take the User ID as the Schema when searching for the table.

My DSN looks like this:

```
'dsn' => "odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM= your host IP;HOSTNAME=your host;DATABASE=your dbname;NAMING=1"
```

As long as the table I'm looking for is in the *LIBL, I don't have to worry about schema at the client.